# Laravel Event within a Command not being fired

Tags: laravel

Here's a simplified version of my Command which attempts to fire an event (obviously there's much more logic in the original).

The event is not being fired. Any idea what I've missed?

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Events\StackEvent;

class StackCommand extends Command
{

    public function handle()
    {
        event(new StackEvent());
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a bit missing there. Can you show your listener code?

Comment: Also the code from event class.

Comment: So, a listener is required? I have many events that have no listeners

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell much. Does `artisan event:list` show the event in question? Have you cleared your event cache?

Comment: An event shouldn't really contain any logic, the purpose of an event class is to hold data which is passed through to one or more listeners. Events and Listeners should be registered in the EventServiceProvider.

Comment: Also from your code, which may be example code, but I cannot tell what your the purpose of your event is. For example, I would expect to see something like event(new OrderHasBeenPaid()); something that is descriptive enough to know what event has happened.

Comment: There are no event listeners. I trigger an Brodcastable event whenever I need. The event contains no logic whatsoever. `artisan event:list` doesn't work in Laravel 5.6. The event is supposed to be broadcasted to Pusher and it is not.